# Counting the number of rows which have column a = x, and column b = y, (groupby, value_count)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, count

Hello I'm trying to learn a bit of new python with some real data, and I'm getting stuck.

The data can be found here (https://edinburghcyclehire.com/open-data/historical). Choosing any month and csv format. I would like to count how many times a trip was made from one station to another station.

After importing with:

```
data = pd.read_csv('09.csv')
```

There are "start_station_id" and "end_station_id" columns.

I would like to count how many times a journey is made from each station to anther station, i.e. how many rows there are: "a to b", "a to c", "b to a", etc. (note: initially "a to b" and "b to a" should be different journeys, although I would also be intereted in hearing how I would run a count which considers "a to b" and "b to a" as the same journey).

I believe I need to use  groupby and/or value_counts but I can't figure out how to implement it after reading the documentation and browsing stack.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **group_by** to find unique combinations of station_a and station_b

#### For example:

```
df = df.groupby(['start_station_name','end_station_name']).count()
count = len(df)
print(count)
```

Note that you must apply an aggregate function to the result of **group_by**. Aggregate functions are functions such as **count(), mean(), max()** etc. These methods will specify how the data in the grouped rows will be aggregated. In this case you use **count()** as we want to count the number of times each journey is made

### Edit

```
df = df.groupby(['start_station_name','end_station_name']).count()
```

Note that calling **count()** in this line ^^^ sets all the columns in the dataframe to the number of times that journey was made.

For Example

```
                                                    started_at  ended_at  duration          ...            end_station_description  end_station_latitude  end_station_longitude
start_station_name  end_station_name    

                                            ...                                                                                
Bristo Square       Bristo Square                            1         1         1          ...                                  1                     1                      1
                    Brunswick Place                          6         6         6          ...                                  6                     6                      6
                    Canonmills                               1         1         1          ...                                  1                     1                      1
                    Castle Street                            1         1         1          ...                                  1                     1                      1
```

Notice that all values for **started_at**, **ended_at** etc are the same. These are all now set to be the count of how many times that journey was made. i.e the Journey from Bristo Square to Brunswick place was made 6 times

Comment: this is much better then my solution!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run 'df = df.groupby(['start_station_name','end_station_name']).count()' I am getting something different from you. I have the counts, but now instead of 'start_station_name' and 'end_station_name' I get an Index with the start station name and end station name combined (see here https://imgur.com/a/3B3bLwv). Are you doing something else to keep the start and end station names as separate columns?

Comment: No not doing anything different. I think it just prints differently to console. Yes, you are right, it resets the index to the grouped_by columns. To avoid this you can set the **as_index** flag to False. For example
`df = df.groupby(['start_station_name','end_station_name'], as_index=False).count()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use boolean algebra!
you can do

`data['start_station_id'] == 183`

to get a bool map where the only `True` where start_Station_id will be 183
similarly you can do

`data['end_station_id'] == 261`

and you can combine both and get

`bmap = (data['start_station_id'] == 183) & (data['end_station_id'] == 261)`

**please note the the parentheses are important!**

this will give you a map where the start station AND the end stasion match, you can then view this data
`data[bmap]`